# R - Execute a function in a file

Tags: r

There is a R file and there is a function getInfo() in it.
I want to run this function in that script file alone.
Is that possible ?
I know running the script command on the file and then running the function name will help.
But then it will also run the rest of stuffs from the script file which i dont want.
What is the best way out here

Comment: Copy the definition of `getInfo()` from the script into a new script or the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `source` on a script file, all the code in that file will be loaded into the R session currently active. Any code that is not in a function, will be executed. I see two options:

1. Put the function in a seperate source file, or even a package if the number of functions grows.
2. Set a global R variable using `option` and retrieve its value in the file to be sourced using `getOption`, making the execution of the non-function code dependend on this option. This does require you to always set this option before sourcing the file, in any project you use it in.

I would go for option 1.